# Custom errors override in ASP.NET MVC area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-areas, custom-errors

I would like to have custom error pages unique to an MVC area. Unfortunately, it appears that the Web.config override system doesn't take the MVC folder structure into account. If I want to override an area called "mobile", I have to create a root project folder (in with Views and Controllers) named "mobile" and put the Web.config in there with the new `customErrors` element.

Is there some better way to do this so that I don't have to create a root folder for any overrides?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been looking for exactly the same thing. One slight change that I do is to use a location element within the main web.config. It's a matter of preference I suppose, but it keeps you from having to create a separate folder and file within your solution. I'd love to know a better way though.

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="error" />
</system.web>
.
.
.
<location path="areaName">
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/areaName/error" />
  </system.web>    
</location>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get a runtime error in my area when it tries to display the error page.