# Custom route for specified errors in web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, custom-errors

I'm having this custom error config in my web.config :

```
<customErrors 
  mode="On"
  defaultRedirect="/common/ErrorPage.html?webconfig">
</customErrors >
```

Now I'm having the need to redirect to a different error page for some special pages but remain the `"/common/ErrorPage.html?webconfig">` like default. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

If your special pages can be in specific ASP.NET MVC area, one way of doing this can be using different location based custom error paths. (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3416635/1095390))

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="error" />
</system.web>
.
.
.
<location path="areaName">
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/areaName/error" />
  </system.web>    
</location>
```

Comment: and I'm developing on ASP.NET 2.0 not MVC